# Work with image captured in webcam with canvas

Tags: html, canvas, webcam, capture

I have a problem.

I need to capture a iamgem from my webcam, and work in canvas with this image.

my code is:

```
  Webcam.set({
            width: 640,
            height: 480,
            image_format: 'jpeg',
            jpeg_quality: 90
        });
        Webcam.attach('#my_camera');


        function take_snapshot() {
            Webcam.snap(function (data_uri) {


                var canvas = document.getElementById("results");
                var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.drawImage(data_uri, 0, 0);


            });
        }
```

This is what I try and I know it is wrong.

So what I need to do to fix this?

Comment: Could you provode a link to the library which produces this Webcam object? Does this display a stream from your webcam? There is a great chance you can directly draw the video, without going through the probably heavy `snap`

Answer (score 0):

`drawImage()` cannot draw data-uris directly so they have be converted to an image element first:

```
Webcam.snap(function (data_uri) {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("results");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var img = new Image();         // create an image element for data-uri
  img.onload = function() {      // add async handler
    ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);   // when loaded, draw image (this)
    // goto next step from here as this block is async
  };
  img.src = data_uri;            // set data-uri as source
});
```

Comment: Thank you, and if i want draw another image over that?

Comment: Simply continue from inside the handler (goto next step comment). Loading images is async so you have to go through load handlers (optionally wrap the code into a promise). If you have a fixed image to draw a tip would be to preload when loading the document so it's available before going through the Webcam object.

Comment: Something like that?

  var img2 = new Image();
                    img2.onload = function() {
                        ctx.drawImage(this, 150, -30);
                    };
                    img2.src = "img/over.png";